# Calculate the number of hours between two dates using NodaTime

Tags: c#, nodatime

I'm trying to use NodaTime to calculate the number of hours between two dates and I get this exception:

"Units contains time units: Hours. Parameter name: units"

This code works fine for years, months, and days.

```
public ElapsedTimeNodaTime(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
{
   var birthday = new LocalDate(StartDate.Year, StartDate.Month, Date.Day);
   var today = new LocalDate(EndDate.Year, EndDate.Month, EndDate.Day);

    Years = Period.Between(birthday, today, PeriodUnits.Years).Years;
    Months = Period.Between(birthday, today, PeriodUnits.Months).Months;
    Days = Period.Between(birthday, today, PeriodUnits.Days).Days;
    Hours = Period.Between(birthday, today, PeriodUnits.Hours).Hours;
}
```

Comment: Side note: I'd advise following .NET naming conventions for parameters. You could also use `var birthday = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(StartDate).Date;` or (in 2.0 using an extension method) `var birthday = StartDate.ToLocalDateTime().Date;`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you've just got dates, the simplest option is to multiply the number of days by 24.

Alternatively, create `LocalDateTime` values instead:

```
Hours = Period.Between(birthday.AtMidnight(), today.AtMidnight(), PeriodUnits.Hours).Hours;
```

Or you could stick to `LocalDateTime` for everything:

```
public ElapsedTimeNodaTime(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
   var birthday = startDate.ToLocalDateTime();
   var today = endDate.ToLocalDateTime();

    Years = Period.Between(birthday, today, PeriodUnits.Years).Years;
    Months = Period.Between(birthday, today, PeriodUnits.Months).Months;
    Days = Period.Between(birthday, today, PeriodUnits.Days).Days;
    Hours = Period.Between(birthday, today, PeriodUnits.Hours).Hours;
}
```

It seems a little pointless though - why redundantly calculate hours when you've got days?

Comment: Good Point. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Besides being redundant, seems like it would also change the context.  I mean, if one talks about "hours since their birthday", one would think time and time zone of birth suddenly become relevant.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Potentially, yes - although my guess is that this is for an assignment where it's been asserted to be okay.